# What is difference between RawECDSA and NoneWithECDSA signature algorithm

Tags: java, digital-signature, pki, xml-signature

I'm searching for a perfect answer what is the basic difference between "**RawECDSA**" and "**NoneWithECDSA**" signature algorithm. At glance I did not see any difference between them, as I know that when **NoneWithECDSA** signature algorithm used it expects already hashed data and no hashing is done on provided data at time of signing. Same as **RawECDSA**.

but I think there is some difference in resultant signature bytes. Can any one help in explaining.

Comment: Where do you get `RawECDSA` from? The 'standard' SunEC provider has `nonewithecdsa` since 7, and BouncyCastle as far back as I can check, but neither has `rawecdsa` (JCA names ignore case).  However, standard ECDSA (like DSA on which it is based) is a randomized algorithm; if you sign the same data with the same key multiple times, the signatures will all be different. See the standards or any text, or (usually most convenient) wikipedia. There is a deterministic variant in RFC6979, but AFAIK no common Java provider has it.

Comment: The IAIK ECCelerate™ library for the Java™ platform gives the RawECDSA algorithm support.

Answer (score 1):

The ouput of the ECDSA algorithm are 2 big numbers (typically called R and S).
Perhaps the 'raw' format just simply concatenates them.

The more common format (e.g. also used in certificates) is to have an ASN.1-DER encoded SEQUENCE containing R and S encoded as INTEGER. This format always starts with byte 0x30 (DER encoding for SEQUENCE)
It's that format that is also used for NoneWithECSA, SHA256WithECDSA, ...